# What is more important when flagging as duplicate? Time or content?

Tags: discussion

So there are these questions:

[If there's only one of each fruit, how could Blackbeard recognize the "Dark Dark" fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/464/if-theres-only-one-of-each-fruit-how-could-blackbeard-recognize-the-dark-dark)

[How is the ability of a Devil Fruit discovered?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/how-is-the-ability-of-a-devil-fruit-discovered?rq=1)

These questions are duplicates, so I flagged the newer question as a duplicate of the older. Though the newer question has a much better and more relevant answer, so in this specific case, should it be flagged the other way around, since we actually want more traffic to the more relevant/better answer?

Comment: While there is some overlap, I don't believe the two questions are *exact* duplicates. One focuses more on a particular character and how he found a particular fruit, while the other is a general question about how the ability a fruit is identified. Currently a cannot answer cannot be given for either, as neither of the accounts have be chronicled or illustrated in anyway by the author.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Masked Man's is a pretty correct cannon answer though. Spandam, Sanji and Blackbeard all mentioned an illustrated book on Devil Fruits, which is how people would know the characteristics and power from. If not recorded yet, someone has to be the first to try.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ About the fact whether they are duplicates. The first question does not ask about how it was found. The answer states this, but the question never asked for it. The question was "how did he recognize the Dark Fruit". Which is a superset of the question "How do you know what power beholds a certain fruit" and that is answered by Masked Man. From the wiki: "There is a book in the Grand Line with Devil Fruits listed. The most notable example is Blackbeard, who, in his search for the Yami Yami no Mi, catalogs a book which was also mentioned by Spandam and Sanji."

Comment: I believe that the former question with Blackbeard could possible a different chronicle account than a generalized method of identification of devil fruits. For an example, what if Blackbeard came about some secret documents chronicling knowledge of certain Devil Fruits, possibly from the Void Century? This could be different than say an updated encyclopedia maintained by the Marines or some third-party about known Devil Fruits. The answers to both might be one and the same, but until the facts are clear, I don't think we should discount one over the other.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ I see. That makes sense. But to go back to the question. Suppose these were duplicates. What should be linked as the original question? The oldest one or the one with the better answer?

Comment: If the end results were clearly the exact duplicate, then I would personally mark the one without a clear answer as the duplicate. If both questions had answers (but none of the definitive), then I would first take a look at the quality of the question and then merge the answers into from the question that is of a lesser quality into the better one. If the quality of both question were the same then I would probably say the older one gets preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technicalities on the mentioned question aside, if the end results of the answer were clearly the exact duplicates of one another, then I would mark the one without a clear answer as the duplicate.

If both questions had answers (but none of them definitives answer the question), then I would first take a look at the quality of the question and then merge the answers into from the question that is of a lesser quality into the better one.

If the quality of both question were the same then I would probably say the older one gets preference.

In short. if there is newer with the better answer (or any at all) it should get preference, otherwise the older question get the preference.

Comment: So for normal users, the appropriate way of action for the second case would be to flag for moderation instead of duplication?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: Note that merging is rarely done, since it destroys the connection of the answers to the original question. Also, slight differences in the way the question is asked may result in extra content or discrepancies when merged.